# Access mem or fs database tables using H2 console

Tags: playframework, h2

I'm trying to access my application's tables in Play! Framework, but I can't find it using the console.
For instance, I have two entity models: `Address` and `Campus`.

I can create objects and save normally, but I would like to see the changes in fs or mem DB, but the H2 console doesn't show the tables `Address` and `Campus`. I'm using the default settings to log in `localhost:9000/@db`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the play framework so far... what is your database URL (if there is a database URL in this framework)?

Comment: Thanks for this, this is a H2 Gui for PlayFramework, saved me a lot of work looking for a GUI!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The correct URL for the inmemory database is:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:name-of-your-play-db
```

Comment: the url is logged in the logging information and you can grab it from there.

Answer (score 10):

Steps I took to get a filesystem H2 database console working where my app is in `c:\play\myapp`:

1. Go to localhost:9000/@db
2. Choose the Generic H2 Server option in the first box
3. For the url enter `jdbc:h2:file:c:/play/myapp/db/h2/play`
4. Username is sa password is blank

Comment: Yes, don't do what I did and add the .h2 extension to the play filename in step 3!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is the database URL, so your application and the H2 Console are using different databases. I suggest to use a database URL of the form `jdbc:h2:~/data/test` or (maybe even better) using an absolute path of the form `jdbc:h2:/data/test`, or when using Windows even with drive letter: `jdbc:h2:c:/data/test`. See the documentation about [where the database files are stored](http://h2database.com/html/faq.html#database_files).

Comment: is that for just the filesystem method?  If I am going to do filesystem, I mine as well use postgres....BUT I would love to connect to the in-memory one just cause it's so fast(no disk i/o).

Comment: never mind, didn't know localhost:9000/@db was a url you could use that actually works!!!! and just hit connect button.  of course, I got an internal error as I had H2 console running....can't do that for some reason.

Comment: I didn't fully understand what your wrote... but keep in mind that when using `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9000/@db` it is relative to the current working directory of the server. An absolute directory would be `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9000//data/test` (two slashes after :9000).

Answer (score 0):

My five cents. In my case (Unix OS) I just managed to make it work using ~/ in my persistence.xml:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:~/data/testxdb" />
```

In this way the Database was created in:
`/Users/lm2a/data/testxdb.mv.db` and starting the console with

```
java -jar h2-2.1.214.jar
```

Finally I could see my Tables.